# Is this a good way to measure disk read/write performance using pv?

Tags: ssd, performance, benchmarks

I wanted to measure read and write performance of a new disk I acquired. For writing I did the following:

```
yes | pv -br > /dev/sda
```

The program `yes` just outputs a single character repeatedly, and very efficiently so that it will almost certainly not be the bottleneck. I pipe this into the disk through `pv`, which monitors the throughput. This gave me around 450 MiB/s.

To measure read performance, I did

```
dd if=/dev/sda | pv -br | dd of=/dev/null
```

This gave me 180 MiB/s.

My questions:

1. Is this a good way to measure read and write performance?
2. If not, what would be a better way?
3. If the figures are relevant, does it make sense that writing is considerably faster than reading?

My hardware consisted of an HP Elitebook 840 G3 with 16 GB RAM booted into live Ubuntu 20.04, and the disk was a Western Digital Green SATA SSD M.2 2280.

Comment: @Community I know you are a bot, but what I am exactly asking is what is under "My questions:". As currently written, it's hard for me to tell what kind of clarifications you are looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with it is it's unstructured. You're just throwing data at a disk, and for that benchmark, it's likely accurate enough. On the disparity between the numbers you're seeing, it's possible you're seeing a write to buffer speed (which should be very fast) and not the write to disk speed. Disks also have their own buffers, which is why it's important to do fairly long write tests.

A tool like [KDiskMark](https://github.com/JonMagon/KDiskMark) (which has obvious overtones of CrystalDiskMark for anyone who's been around Windows benchmarks in the past decade) will structure tests into a few different read and write patterns that better reflect specific workloads.

[image]

[Gnome Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) (pre-installed on Ubuntu) also has some lightweight benchmarking which will offer you a quick overview of performance over time (drives have buffers that get slower when full), as well as latency.

[image]